# Troubleshooting "parse error, unexpected '>'" error

Tags: php

I am getting this error that is reading

> Parse error: parse error, unexpected '>' in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 11

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("include/header.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])){;
header("Location:includeindex.php");
exit;
 }
 else{
TopNavigation("about Me -ECA236","About Me",$_SESSION['name']);
echo "<p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9 </p>
echo "<p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years </p>
echo "<p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament      </p>
echo "<p>After I get done with this degree I am want to go back for Web Design </p>
echo "<p>since half my classes are web design now. I enjoy camping,bon fires and </p>
echo "<p>playing video games, hanging out with friends and family.</p>
Footer();
   }
 ?>
```

I have tried adding ; to the end and " to the end but the same thing pops up. Can someone sees what I am doing wrong.

Here is the error i get when i add "; to the end of those:

> Warning: include(include/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'include/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 3
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\about.php:3) in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 5

Comment: use like this `echo "<p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9 </p>";`

Comment: Did you try to put *both* at the end, in the right order?

Comment: You do not need to use echo to output larger chunks of HTML. Close the PHP, output the HTML and then open PHP again. See my answer below for an example.

Comment: As @hakre says, close the PHP. If you HAVE to do this while in PHP mode, at least use a HEREDOC, which is designed for multiline strings: http://php.net/heredoc

Comment: @Marc B: Single and double quote strings are multiline as well.

Comment: @hakre: Yes, they can be, but you have to escape any embedded quotes. A HEREDOC requires no escaping at all, unless you want to embed a literal `{` and/or `$`.

Comment: @Marc B: That's what NOWDOC then is for. However that specific HTML does not contain any quotes, so that's why I would not suggest HEREDOC in the first place. It does work however.

Comment: A single here-/now-doc is far more efficient and easier to read than multiline echoes, regardless of variable/quoting/escaping requirements. But best would be to drop out of PHP mode and let any decent editor colorize everything as HTML anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
echo "<p>playing video games, hanging out with friends and family.</p>
```

You need:

```
echo "<p>playing video games, hanging out with friends and family.</p>";
```

Comment: Or the `echo "` on each next line is redundant and only one `";` is missing at the end of all output.

Comment: i do that fix and i get another error

Comment: i already did all that but i get new errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a quote `";` to the end of your `echo` lines

Comment: While technically incorrect (looking), that's not an error - it only adds a blank statement as the first statement of the if block.  Strange, but won't throw an error.

Comment: That's true, but wouldn't cause the code to break. It's a valid empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a quote and a semicolon at the end of each echo line.

Generally speaking, any time you open a quote on a line in PHP, you'll also need to close it, and every line (with a few exceptions, such as flow-control statements, etc.) will need to be terminated by a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the quotes :

echo "

Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9 **";**

Comment: i do that and i get another error

Comment: what's the new error you are getting ?

Comment: Warning: include(include/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'include/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 3

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\about.php:3) in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 5

Comment: do you have the file called header.php under the folder called include ?

Comment: include ("includes/header.php"); header("Location:includindex.php"); is what I have

Comment: you need to have a physical file called header.php here --> C:\wamp\www\include\header.php

Comment: yes I do have that..I dont know what else it is doing.. I am trying all my sources...

Answer (score 0):

All of your echo lines need to close their speechmarks and finish with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing any of the echo statements at all. The below should work:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("include/header.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
header("Location:includeindex.php");
exit;
 }
 else{
TopNavigation("about Me -ECA236","About Me",$_SESSION['name']);
echo "<p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9 </p>";
echo "<p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years </p>";
echo "<p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament      </p>";
echo "<p>After I get done with this degree I am want to go back for Web Design </p>";
echo "<p>since half my classes are web design now. I enjoy camping,bon fires and </p>";
echo "<p>playing video games, hanging out with friends and family.</p>";
Footer();
   }
 ?>
```

*I also see a semi-colon on Line 4 which I don't think is needed* - Removed it above.

Comment: Still needs semicolons on all other lines.

Comment: If you mean the echo statements I realised after first posting and added these in after.

Comment: Why the semicolon after the first if statement?

Comment: I stated that I didn't believe it was needed. I'll remove this from my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
session_start();
include_once ("include/header.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header("Location:includeindex.php");
    exit;
}
else {
    TopNavigation("about Me -ECA236", "About Me", $_SESSION['name']);
    echo "<p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9</p>";
    echo "<p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years</p>";
    echo "<p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament</p>";
    echo "<p>After I get done with this degree I am want to go back for Web Design</p>";
    echo "<p>since half my classes are web design now. I enjoy camping,bon fires and</p>";
    echo "<p>playing video games, hanging out with friends and family.</p>";
    Footer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your file is wrong. The following example should fix it, however, the message just means that part of your output is indeed code because you missed to properly use the `"` quotes around strings. Keep in mind that strings work over multiple lines as well, so this is probably easier to understand:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("include/header.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
  header("Location:includeindex.php");
  exit;
} else {
  TopNavigation("about Me -ECA236","About Me",$_SESSION['name']);
  echo "
    <p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9 </p>
    <p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years </p>
    <p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament      </p>
    <p>After I get done with this degree I am want to go back for Web Design </p>
    <p>since half my classes are web design now. I enjoy camping,bon fires and </p>
    <p>playing video games, hanging out with friends and family.</p>
    " # string ends here
    ;
  Footer();
}
?>
```

Or even better as this is PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("include/header.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
  header("Location:includeindex.php");
  exit;
} else {
  TopNavigation("about Me -ECA236","About Me",$_SESSION['name']);
  ?>
    <p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9 </p>
    <p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years </p>
    <p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament</p>
    <p>After I get done with this degree I am want to go back for Web Design </p>
    <p>since half my classes are web design now. I enjoy camping,bon fires and </p>
    <p>playing video games, hanging out with friends and family.</p>
  <?php
  Footer();
}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting these errors now Warning: include(include/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'include/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 3

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\about.php:3) in C:\wamp\www\about.php on line 6

Comment: In which path is the file `include/header.php`? In case you wonder what include does and what the error message means, checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else said, you need the quotes and semi colons.  But that's also ignoring that there are less verbose (and less overhead) methods of doing this.  For example, you could do all under one echo statement:

```
echo"
  <p>>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9</p>
  <p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years</p>
  <p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament</p>
";
```

Or, an alternative method is

```
$content = " <<<END
  <p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9</p>
  <p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years</p>
  <p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament</p>
END;

echo $content;
```

The best possible solution, if you're going to be doing a ton of non-php, is just to close the PHP tag and do it with straight HTML where you don't have to worry about quotes and semicolons at all!

```
?>
  <p>Here is a little about me. I am a mother of twin girls who are 9</p>
  <p>I been married for 5 years but been with my husband for 11 years</p>
  <p>I am attending college for Computer Programming and Database Mangament</p>
<?php
```

My point is that I see a lot of `<?php>` and `</php>` repetition as well as a ton of `echo` repetition on SO examples.  Does it work?  Sure.  But it's unnecessary.  It slows you down, and creates more opportunities to screw up.  And, it's just plain ugly!  I don't want to debug it!